# Merge two arrays into one and get each item's occurrence in their parent array

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have two arrays of dates. I want to merge them into one array that stores each (distinct) dates and their occurrences in their parent arrays.

For example:

```cs
var today = new DateTime (year:2022, month:01, day:01);
var firstDateArray = new DateTime[] { today.AddDays(1), today.AddDays(7), today, today.AddDays(3), today };
var secondDateArray = new DateTime[] { today.AddDays(7), today, today.AddDays(3), today.AddDays(3), today.AddDays(1) };
```

I want to get something like this as a result.
[image]

How do I go about this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I used a tuple `(DateTime, int, int)` to represent the data:

```
List<(DateTime, int, int)> result = firstDateArray.
            Concat(secondDateArray).
            Distinct().
            Select(x => (
                x,
                firstDateArray.Where(y => y == x).Count(),
                secondDateArray.Where(z => z == x).Count()
                )).
            ToList();
```

Comment: Like the answer, short and sweet. However, I would be interested to see Linq run times for handling distinct vs handling them yourself without merging and keeping track and what was found.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.GroupBy`, `.Select`, and `.Join` for this:

```cs
var today = new DateTime (year:2022, month:01, day:01);
var firstDateArray = new DateTime[] { today.AddDays(1), today.AddDays(7), today, today.AddDays(3), today };
var secondDateArray = new DateTime[] { today.AddDays(7), today, today.AddDays(3), today.AddDays(3), today.AddDays(1) };

var firstGrouped = firstDateArray
        .GroupBy(d => d)
        .Select(g => new { Date = g.Key, Count = g.Count() });
var secondGrouped  = secondDateArray
        .GroupBy(d => d)
    .Select(g => new { Date = g.Key, Count = g.Count() });

var joined = firstGrouped
    .Join(secondGrouped, f => f.Date, s => s.Date, (f, s) => new { Date = f.Date, FirstCount = f.Count, SecondCount = s.Count })
    .OrderBy(j => j.Date)
    .ToList();
```

`GroupBy` basically collects items with a common key (in this case the `DateTime`) and then lets you iterate through the collections.

`Join` takes 4 arguments: the second enumerable, the key selector for the first, the key selector for the second (it uses these to facilitate the join), and the result selector to produce the result you want.

Documentation:

- [GroupBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=net-6.0)
- [Select](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=net-6.0)
- [Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.join?view=net-6.0)
- [OrderBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=net-6.0)
- [ToList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolist?view=net-6.0)

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/DOM80668)

[image]